# Never ending do-while loop with regex

Tags: php, regex, do-while, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to run a series of patterns on a XLIFF file. A sample:

```
  <trans-unit id="1">
    <source> I like "sausages". </source>
    <target> J'aime bien les « sausices » </target>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="2">
    <source> I like "sausages". </source>
    <target> J'aime bien les «sausices» </target>
  </trans-unit>
```

I parse the file, and then I run each pattern on each target element.

```
    foreach($patterns as $p) {
        if (preg_match($p['find'], $tu[0]->target, $dummy)) {
            do {
                $targetText = $tu[0]->target;
                $tu[0]->target = preg_replace($p['find'], $p['repl'], $targetText, -1, $count);
            } while ($count);
        }
    }
```

For example, I have an array with patters:

```
        $patterns[1] = array(
            'find' => "/[«‹]\K(?!\x{00A0})\s/imu",
            'repl' => "&#8239;"
            );
        $patterns[2] = array(
            'find' => "/[«‹]\K(?!\p{Zs})/imu",
            'repl' => "&#8239;"
            );
```

Patter 1 should match trans-unit 1 above, and pattern 2 should match trans-unit 2. Pattern 1 works fine, but if I run pattern 2 (only or both) the loop never ends. The replacement basically replaces a normal (breaking) space after « or ‹ (pattern 1) with a narrow breaking space or inserts it if there's no space at all (pattern 1).

I would say the issue has to do with the second regex, but I can't figure out what is wrong with that expression. Any tips?

Comment: sometimes people add sample data to their questions....

Comment: Sorry, I did't think it would be relevant. Added now, thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with the question but in french it is written `saucisse`

Comment: I was making a very erroneous assumption: that my pattern `\p{Zs}` would match `&#8239;`, which is not the case. Adding "&#8239;" to muy pattern 2 (i.e. `'find' => "/[«‹]\K(?!\p{Zs}|&#8239;)/imu",`) seems to fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I can't post an answer and therefore I can't vote the question as solved.

Comment: I've just came to the same conclusion. But, why can't you post it as an answer?

Comment: I don't know, I get the `We are no longer accepting answers from this account.`. I only posted one answer once, so I don't think I "have contributed many low-quality answers in the past".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\p{Zs}` pattern does not match `&#8239;`, therefore add `&#8239;` to the lookahead condition in the second pattern:

```
'find' => "/[«‹]\K(?!\p{Zs}|&#8239;)/iu",) 
                            ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Exactly, as I posted in the comments on Nov 17. Thans, Wiktor :)